# CorDapp with java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl with IBM JDK 8

Tags: corda

I got the following error message when I tried to build a CorDapp sample. If it is caused by certificate missing the header and footer lines, how can I get a correct certification?

```
Logs can be found in                    : /opt/corda/samples/cordapp-example/workflows-java/build/nodes/PartyA/logs
java.io.IOException: Sequence tag error
... ...
    at net.corda.node.Corda.main(Corda.kt:13)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl
    at net.corda.serialization.internal.DefaultWhitelist.<clinit>(DefaultWhitelist.kt:65)
... ...
    at net.corda.cliutils.CordaCliWrapperKt.start(CordaCliWrapper.kt:72)
    at net.corda.node.Corda.main(Corda.kt:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl
```

Comment: it only works with Oracle JDK 8. It's a pre-requisite to run `corda`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Corda getting started guide [here](https://docs.corda.net/getting-set-up.html)

Java 8 is required and the following JDK's have been tested

- Oracle JDK
- Amazon Corretto
- Red Hat’s OpenJDK

Note: OpenJDK builds usually exclude JavaFX, which Corda's GUI tools require.